# How to handle multiple records in Kafka Consumer?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Hi I am working on Confluent Kafka Consumer. I have multiple records in my broker. I want to handle all the records now. Below is my implementation of consumer.

```
public ConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord> Consume(string topic)
    {
      ConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord> result;
      try
      {
        result = consumer.Consume();
        Commit(result);
        return result;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        this.logger.Error("KafkaClient", $"Error sending message '{e.Message}'");
        return null;
      }
    }
```

[image: Result retuurned from consumer]
If there are multiple records inside Broker, Then one event/message I will get a time using GenericRecord. If there are multiple records Then how to handle consumer effectively? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would just loop. See the examples

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroGeneric/Program.cs

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cts.Token);

        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {consumeResult.Message.Key}\nValue: {consumeResult.Value}");
    }
    catch (ConsumeException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Consume error: {e.Error.Reason}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If there are multiple records, Then If I put while loop, Then it will fetch multiple records right?

Comment: It'll keep consuming, yes. Whether you get more records, depends on the Producer

Comment: So When executing  var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cts.Token); it will consume only one record right? nd again in next loop it consumes second record? Am I right?

Comment: Thanks. This is my consumer config.  BootstrapServers = kafkaConfig.BootstrapServers,
        GroupId = "ProductEvent" Do I need to add any other settings? I want to read data from last read.

Comment: I just debugged my code after adding while loop. I have multiple records in my broker. but returned only one record. I can see offset 5(5 times I added data). I have added screen shot.